# JQuery Animation overshooting

Tags: jquery

Example: http://wispinternet.com/glencoe/

When the page is first loaded, the first time you mouse over one of the tabs in the top right, the tab moves out further than intended, then moves back to the intended position. After that, it works as intended.

Not sure what's causing this, as it all looks ok. I tried changing the easing style to linear, but it has no effect. I'm no JQuery expert, although I guess it could be a problem with my CSS.

Apologies if viewing the source shows the HTML inline, seems to be a bug with Dreamweaver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add this CSS to your `li`s: `margin: 70px 0px 0px;`.
Also, in Firefox the images have a blue thick border. You should CSS them away.

**edit** Better answer:

Change your jquery to this:

```
$("#nav li").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({marginTop:50},{duration:500})
});

$("#nav li").mouseout(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({marginTop:70},{duration:500})
});
```

For some reason it seems to work this way.

Comment: You don't think that blue border looks pretty? :P

Comment: @alex: I've loved it since the 90's!

Comment: You define the li as 70px 0px 0px 0px in the page's CSS; it's that extra 0px that's likely screwing stuff up.

Comment: Whoops, got rid of the blue border earlier but messing with the CSS brought it back. Fixed that.

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it. I tried it with margin-top, but I guess it doesn't accept that.

Comment: Yeah I did that too. It looks like it only accepts js-style css properties.

Comment: "Shorthand CSS properties (e.g. margin, background, border) are not supported. For example, if you want to retrieve the rendered margin, use: $(elem).css('marginTop') and $(elem).css('marginRight'), and so on."

Comment: @methodin: thanks for that, now we know jQuery was only trying its best :-)

Answer (score 1):

You have a `:hover` pseudo class on your `li` elements. Remove the negative `top` property.

Comment: Forgot about that, removed it now, though no luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to set the style="margin:70px 0px 0px 0px" inline in each li element it would work. When your first mouseover there is no visible margin property inline so jquery assigns 0px 0px 0px 0px which is why you see the jump.

```
<li style="margin:70px 0px 0px 0px"><a href="home.php"><img src="images/home_tab.png" alt="Home" width="65" height="200" /></a></li>
<li style="margin:70px 0px 0px 0px"><a href="gallery.php"><img src="images/gallery_tab.png" alt="Gallery" width="65" height="200" /></a></li>
<li style="margin:70px 0px 0px 0px"><a href="booking.php"><img src="images/booking_tab.png" alt="Booking" width="65" height="200" /></a></li>
<li style="margin:70px 0px 0px 0px"><a href="contact.php"><img src="images/contact_tab.png" alt="Contact" width="65" height="200" /></a></li>
```

You could also just use margin-top:70px and animate that specific property.

Comment: Why does it have to be defined inline rather than in the top CSS? Sorry, if I'm being a bit dense :P